# Something wrong with format of json

Tags: json, google-maps, maps, geojson

I am using this json data

```
    {
        "type":"Polygon",
        "coordinates":[[[72.8282833,19.0175056],[72.8285408,19.017849],[72.8292274,19.0185356],[72.8302574,19.0188789],[72.8309441,19.0195656],[72.8311157,19.0200806],[72.8311157,19.0207672],[72.8312874,19.0212822],[72.833004,19.0229988],[72.8333473,19.0240288],[72.8336906,19.0243721],[72.834034,19.0254021],[72.8343773,19.0257454],[72.8347206,19.0267754],[72.8350639,19.0271187],[72.8354073,19.0281487],[72.8357506,19.028492],[72.8357506,19.0288353],[72.8354073,19.0291786],[72.8352356,19.0296936],[72.8352356,19.0303802],[72.8354073,19.0308952],[72.8357506,19.0312386],[72.8360939,19.0322685],[72.8371239,19.0326118],[72.8374672,19.0329552],[72.8379822,19.0331268],[72.8384972,19.0329552],[72.8388405,19.0326118],[72.8393555,19.0324402],[72.8398705,19.0326118],[72.8412437,19.0339851],[72.8415871,19.0350151],[72.8422737,19.0357018],[72.8427887,19.0358734],[72.8434753,19.0358734],[72.8439903,19.0360451],[72.8443336,19.0363884],[72.8448486,19.0365601],[72.8455353,19.0365601],[72.8460503,19.0367317],[72.8463936,19.037075],[72.8474236,19.0374184],[72.8475952,19.0379333],[72.8475952,19.0399933],[72.8474236,19.0405083],[72.8469086,19.0406799],[72.8462219,19.0406799],[72.8457069,19.0408516],[72.8453636,19.0418816],[72.8439903,19.0432549],[72.8434753,19.0434265],[72.8427887,19.0434265],[72.8422737,19.0435982],[72.8419304,19.0439415],[72.8414154,19.0441132],[72.8400421,19.0441132],[72.8395271,19.0442848],[72.8393555,19.0447998],[72.8393555,19.0468597],[72.8395271,19.0473747],[72.8415871,19.0494347],[72.8421021,19.0496063],[72.8427887,19.0496063],[72.8433037,19.0494347],[72.844677,19.0480614],[72.8450203,19.0470314],[72.8455353,19.0468597],[72.8469086,19.0468597],[72.8474236,19.0470314],[72.8477669,19.0473747],[72.8487968,19.047718],[72.8487968,19.0480614],[72.8484535,19.0484047],[72.8481102,19.0494347],[72.8457069,19.0518379],[72.8455353,19.0523529],[72.8455353,19.0537262],[72.8457069,19.0542412],[72.8462219,19.0544128],[72.8475952,19.0544128],[72.8481102,19.0542412],[72.8487968,19.0535545],[72.8491402,19.0525246],[72.8508568,19.050808],[72.8512001,19.049778],[72.8518867,19.0490913],[72.8522301,19.0490913],[72.8525734,19.0494347],[72.8530884,19.0496063],[72.8544617,19.0496063],[72.8549767,19.049778],[72.8563499,19.0511513],[72.8566933,19.0521812],[72.8573799,19.0528679],[72.8578949,19.0530396],[72.8640747,19.0530396],[72.8645897,19.0532112],[72.8652763,19.0538979],[72.865448,19.0544128],[72.865448,19.0550995],[72.8656197,19.0556145],[72.8661346,19.0557861],[72.8668213,19.0557861],[72.8673363,19.0559578],[72.8690529,19.0576744],[72.8695679,19.0578461],[72.8709412,19.0578461],[72.8714561,19.0576744],[72.8717995,19.0573311],[72.8721428,19.0573311],[72.8731728,19.0583611],[72.8736877,19.0585327],[72.8742027,19.0583611],[72.8745461,19.0580177],[72.875061,19.0578461],[72.875576,19.0580177],[72.8759193,19.0590477],[72.8769493,19.059391],[72.8772926,19.060421],[72.877636,19.0607643],[72.8779793,19.0617943],[72.8784943,19.0619659],[72.8798676,19.0619659],[72.8803825,19.0617943],[72.8807259,19.0607643],[72.8814125,19.0600777],[72.8819275,19.059906],[72.8826141,19.059906],[72.8831291,19.0597343],[72.8834724,19.059391],[72.8839874,19.0592194],[72.8845024,19.059391],[72.8848457,19.0597343],[72.8853607,19.059906],[72.8860474,19.059906],[72.8865623,19.0600777],[72.8869057,19.060421],[72.8874207,19.0605927],[72.8879356,19.060421],[72.888279,19.0600777],[72.8886223,19.0600777],[72.8889656,19.060421],[72.8899956,19.0607643],[72.8917122,19.0624809],[72.8922272,19.0626526],[72.8942871,19.0626526],[72.8948021,19.0624809],[72.8949738,19.0619659],[72.8949738,19.0605927],[72.8948021,19.0600777],[72.8937721,19.0597343],[72.8927422,19.0587044],[72.8917122,19.0583611],[72.8896523,19.0563011],[72.8894806,19.0557861],[72.8896523,19.0552711],[72.8906822,19.0549278],[72.8913689,19.0542412],[72.8913689,19.0538979],[72.8906822,19.0532112],[72.8901672,19.0530396],[72.8894806,19.0530396],[72.8889656,19.0528679],[72.8886223,19.0525246],[72.8881073,19.0523529],[72.886734,19.0523529],[72.886219,19.0521812],[72.8858757,19.0518379],[72.8853607,19.0516663],[72.8846741,19.0516663],[72.8841591,19.0518379],[72.8838158,19.0521812],[72.8834724,19.0521812],[72.8833008,19.0516663],[72.8833008,19.0509796],[72.8831291,19.0504646],[72.8827858,19.0501213],[72.8827858,19.049778],[72.8831291,19.0494347],[72.8833008,19.0489197],[72.8833008,19.0454865],[72.8831291,19.0449715],[72.8826141,19.0447998],[72.8784943,19.0447998],[72.8779793,19.0449715],[72.8772926,19.0456581],[72.8769493,19.0466881],[72.8759193,19.047718],[72.875576,19.048748],[72.875061,19.0489197],[72.8736877,19.0489197],[72.8731728,19.048748],[72.8728294,19.0484047],[72.8717995,19.0480614],[72.8714561,19.047718],[72.8704262,19.0473747],[72.8702545,19.0468597],[72.8702545,19.0461731],[72.8700829,19.0456581],[72.8697395,19.0453148],[72.8693962,19.0442848],[72.8690529,19.0439415],[72.8688812,19.0434265],[72.8690529,19.0429115],[72.8700829,19.0418816],[72.8702545,19.0413666],[72.8702545,19.0406799],[72.8700829,19.0401649],[72.8697395,19.0398216],[72.8697395,19.0394783],[72.8700829,19.039135],[72.8704262,19.038105],[72.8709412,19.0379333],[72.8723145,19.0379333],[72.8728294,19.0377617],[72.8735161,19.037075],[72.8736877,19.0365601],[72.8735161,19.0360451],[72.8728294,19.0353584],[72.8723145,19.0351868],[72.8716278,19.0351868],[72.8711128,19.0350151],[72.8711128,19.0346718],[72.8714561,19.0343285],[72.8716278,19.0338135],[72.8716278,19.0324402],[72.8714561,19.0319252],[72.8709412,19.0317535],[72.8695679,19.0317535],[72.8690529,19.0315819],[72.8688812,19.0310669],[72.8688812,19.0303802],[72.8687096,19.0298653],[72.8683662,19.0295219],[72.8681946,19.029007],[72.8683662,19.028492],[72.8697395,19.0271187],[72.8707695,19.0267754],[72.8709412,19.0262604],[72.8709412,19.0255737],[72.8707695,19.0250587],[72.8704262,19.0247154],[72.8704262,19.0243721],[72.8711128,19.0236855],[72.8714561,19.0236855],[72.8717995,19.0240288],[72.8723145,19.0242004],[72.8730011,19.0242004],[72.8735161,19.0240288],[72.8742027,19.0233421],[72.8742027,19.0229988],[72.8738594,19.0226555],[72.8736877,19.0221405],[72.8738594,19.0216255],[72.8743744,19.0214539],[72.875061,19.0214539],[72.875576,19.0212822],[72.8757477,19.0207672],[72.8757477,19.0193939],[72.875576,19.0188789],[72.8752327,19.0185356],[72.8748894,19.0175056],[72.8742027,19.016819],[72.8736877,19.0166473],[72.8730011,19.0166473],[72.8724861,19.0164757],[72.8721428,19.0161324],[72.8716278,19.0159607],[72.8709412,19.0159607],[72.8704262,19.0161324],[72.8700829,19.0164757],[72.8697395,19.0164757],[72.8693962,19.0154457],[72.8687096,19.0147591],[72.8681946,19.0145874],[72.8668213,19.0145874],[72.8663063,19.0144157],[72.8661346,19.0139008],[72.8661346,19.0132141],[72.865963,19.0126991],[72.865448,19.0125275],[72.8647614,19.0125275],[72.8642464,19.0123558],[72.8642464,19.0120125],[72.8652763,19.0116692],[72.865448,19.0111542],[72.865448,19.0097809],[72.8652763,19.0092659],[72.8645897,19.0085793],[72.8635597,19.0082359],[72.8632164,19.0078926],[72.8621864,19.0075493],[72.8618431,19.0065193],[72.8613281,19.0063477],[72.8585815,19.0063477],[72.8580666,19.0065193],[72.8570366,19.0075493],[72.8565216,19.0077209],[72.8560066,19.0075493],[72.855835,19.0070343],[72.8560066,19.0065193],[72.8563499,19.006176],[72.8563499,19.0058327],[72.8560066,19.0054893],[72.855835,19.0049744],[72.8560066,19.0044594],[72.8563499,19.0041161],[72.8563499,19.0037727],[72.8560066,19.0034294],[72.8556633,19.0023994],[72.85532,19.0020561],[72.8551483,19.0015411],[72.8551483,19.0008545],[72.8549767,19.0003395],[72.85429,18.9996529],[72.853775,18.9994812],[72.85326,18.9996529],[72.8525734,19.0003395],[72.8524017,19.0008545],[72.8524017,19.0029144],[72.8522301,19.0034294],[72.8518867,19.0037727],[72.8517151,19.0042877],[72.8517151,19.0049744],[72.8518867,19.0054893],[72.8522301,19.0058327],[72.8524017,19.0063477],[72.8524017,19.0090942],[72.8525734,19.0096092],[72.8529167,19.0099525],[72.8529167,19.0102959],[72.8524017,19.0104675],[72.8518867,19.0102959],[72.8517151,19.0097809],[72.8517151,19.0077209],[72.8515434,19.007206],[72.8512001,19.0068626],[72.8508568,19.0058327],[72.8503418,19.005661],[72.8482819,19.005661],[72.8477669,19.0054893],[72.8475952,19.0049744],[72.8477669,19.0044594],[72.8481102,19.0041161],[72.8482819,19.0036011],[72.8482819,19.0015411],[72.8484535,19.0010262],[72.8487968,19.0006828],[72.8489685,19.0001678],[72.8487968,18.9996529],[72.8477669,18.9986229],[72.8475952,18.9981079],[72.8475952,18.9974213],[72.8474236,18.9969063],[72.8469086,18.9967346],[72.8448486,18.9967346],[72.8443336,18.996563],[72.843647,18.9958763],[72.8434753,18.9953613],[72.8434753,18.9946747],[72.8433037,18.9941597],[72.842617,18.9934731],[72.8421021,18.9933014],[72.8414154,18.9933014],[72.8409004,18.9931297],[72.8405571,18.9920998],[72.8395271,18.9917564],[72.8395271,18.9914131],[72.8398705,18.9910698],[72.8398705,18.9907265],[72.8384972,18.9893532],[72.8374672,18.9890099],[72.8372955,18.9884949],[72.8372955,18.9857483],[72.8371239,18.9852333],[72.8367805,18.98489],[72.8366089,18.984375],[72.8366089,18.9823151],[72.8364372,18.9818001],[72.8360939,18.9814568],[72.8359222,18.9809418],[72.8359222,18.9802551],[72.8357506,18.9797401],[72.8354073,18.9793968],[72.8352356,18.9788818],[72.8352356,18.9768219],[72.8350639,18.9763069],[72.834549,18.9761353],[72.8331757,18.9761353],[72.8326607,18.9763069],[72.832489,18.9768219],[72.832489,18.9802551],[72.8326607,18.9807701],[72.833004,18.9811134],[72.8331757,18.9816284],[72.8331757,18.9823151],[72.8333473,18.98283],[72.8336906,18.9831734],[72.8338623,18.9836884],[72.8338623,18.9864349],[72.834034,18.9869499],[72.8343773,18.9872932],[72.834549,18.9878082],[72.8343773,18.9883232],[72.8333473,18.9886665],[72.8331757,18.9891815],[72.8331757,18.9912415],[72.8333473,18.9917564],[72.8343773,18.9920998],[72.8347206,18.9931297],[72.8350639,18.9934731],[72.8350639,18.9938164],[72.834034,18.9941597],[72.8338623,18.9946747],[72.8338623,18.996048],[72.834034,18.996563],[72.8347206,18.9972496],[72.8357506,18.9975929],[72.8359222,18.9981079],[72.8359222,18.9987946],[72.8360939,18.9993095],[72.8364372,18.9996529],[72.8366089,19.0001678],[72.8366089,19.0015411],[72.8367805,19.0020561],[72.8371239,19.0023994],[72.8372955,19.0029144],[72.8371239,19.0034294],[72.8360939,19.0044594],[72.8357506,19.0054893],[72.8354073,19.0058327],[72.8352356,19.0063477],[72.8352356,19.0077209],[72.8354073,19.0082359],[72.8359222,19.0084076],[72.8372955,19.0084076],[72.8378105,19.0082359],[72.8381538,19.0078926],[72.8384972,19.0078926],[72.8386688,19.0084076],[72.8386688,19.0090942],[72.8388405,19.0096092],[72.8398705,19.0099525],[72.8402138,19.0109825],[72.8405571,19.0113258],[72.8407288,19.0118408],[72.8407288,19.0139008],[72.8405571,19.0144157],[72.8402138,19.0144157],[72.8395271,19.0137291],[72.8391838,19.0126991],[72.8378105,19.0113258],[72.8372955,19.0111542],[72.8359222,19.0111542],[72.8354073,19.0113258],[72.8347206,19.0120125],[72.8347206,19.0123558],[72.8350639,19.0126991],[72.8350639,19.0130424],[72.8347206,19.0133858],[72.8343773,19.0144157],[72.8338623,19.0145874],[72.8331757,19.0145874],[72.8326607,19.0147591],[72.8323174,19.0151024],[72.8312874,19.0154457],[72.8309441,19.015789],[72.8306007,19.015789],[72.8295708,19.0147591],[72.8290558,19.0145874],[72.8285408,19.0147591],[72.8278542,19.0154457],[72.8276825,19.0159607],[72.8276825,19.0166473],[72.8277683,19.0171623],[72.8282833,19.017]]]
    }
```

to plot on http://geojson.io/
Is it a syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this i have ploted the polygon on googlemap and the syntax i got as following

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              61.17187499999999,
              59.712097173322924
            ],
            [
              116.01562499999999,
              59.5343180010956
            ],
            [
              136.40625,
              41.77131167976407
            ],
            [
              116.3671875,
              10.487811882056683
            ],
            [
              71.015625,
              6.315298538330033
            ],
            [
              36.2109375,
              23.88583769986199
            ],
            [
              61.17187499999999,
              59.712097173322924
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

link to the polygon which i have created

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4f79e65b677f7171c7b1